# Google Map API and Links

Tags: php, api, google-maps

I am trying to add a link into the pop-up text bubble of a marker in Google Maps through the API.  I have successfully run the below code:

```
echo '<marker lat="43.91892" lng="-78.89231" html="Albertus Magnus College&lt;br&gt;Link to Admissions" label="Albertus Magnus College" />';
```

But once I actually try to add the link it fails. Like this:

```
echo '<marker lat="43.91892" lng="-78.89231" html="Albertus Magnus College&lt;br&gt;&lt;a href='http://www.albertus.edu/admission/index.shtml'&gt;Admissions&lt;\/a&gt;" label="Albertus Magnus College" />';
```

Does anyone know how to successfully write this code?  I am writing it into PHP because I have some other functionality that won't let me just write it in XML.

Update:  I got it to work like this for some reason...

```
$window2a_url = '&lt;a href=&apos;http://www.albertus.edu/admission/index.shtml&apos;&gt;Admissions';
echo '<marker lat="41.331304" lng="-72.921438" html=" Albertus Magnus College&lt;br&gt;';
echo $window2a_url;
echo '" label="Albertus Magnus College" />';
```

I had to escape the apostrophes...  If anyone has a more elegant solution, I am all ears!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer:

```
$window2a_url = '&lt;a
href=&apos;http://www.albertus.edu/admission/index.shtml&apos;&gt;Admissions';
echo '<marker lat="41.331304" lng="-72.921438" html=" Albertus Magnus College&lt;br&gt;';
echo $window2a_url;
echo '" label="Albertus Magnus College" />';
```

I had to escape the apostrophes...

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are putting an apostrophe (') inside the string.
You should use an escape character (may be "\", I don't know PHP's syntax) near the apostrophe.

Comment: for some reason when I tired that I still got an error. But you were right about the "\" being PHP's escape character.

Answer (score 0):

what the other chap said.

try:

```
echo '<marker lat="43.91892" lng="-78.89231" html="Albertus Magnus College&lt;br&gt;&lt;a href=\'http://www.albertus.edu/admission/index.shtml\'&gt;Admissions&lt;\/a&gt;" label="Albertus Magnus College" />';
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is as friol indicates that you end the echo using an apastophe in the link, the code below should work because I escaped the apastrophe (' to \')

```
echo '<marker lat="43.91892" lng="-78.89231" html="Albertus Magnus College<br><a href=\'http://www.albertus.edu/admission/index.shtml\'>Admissions</a>" label="Albertus Magnus College" />';
```